# Model collections of the same class held by several other classes

Tags: asp.net, castle-activerecord

How do I model the following using Castle ActiveRecord?

I have two classes, Customer and Task.

I would like to reuse a third class, Note, stored in a Collection in each of the Customer and Task classes.

```
public class Note
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{ 
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public IList<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public IList<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}
```

I would then like to be able to pass the Notes collection to a Gridview, Listview or Repeater in the relevant ASP.Net page for the Customer or Task classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We settled on the following pattern:

```
[ActiveRecord]
public class Note
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    [BelongsTo]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    [BelongsTo]
    public Customer Task{ get; set; }
}

[ActiveRecord]
public class Customer
{ 
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [HasMany]
    public IList<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}

[ActiveRecord]
public class Task
{ 
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [HasMany]
    public IList<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is to implement a type hierarchy. You can read about it [here](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/usersguide/typehierarchy.html).